# ¿Cómo personalizar el mensaje de error al ingresar un dato repetido?

Tags: python, web2py

Tengo esta tabla:

```
db.define_table('registro',
                Field('numero_documento', 'string', unique=True),
                Field('remitente', 'string'),
                Field('usuario', 'reference usuarios'),
                Field('fecha_ingreso', 'date', default=now),
                format='%(numero_documento)s'
                )

db.registro.numero_documento.requires = IS_NOT_IN_DB(db, 'registro.numero_documento')
```

Donde el campo `numero_documento` está definido como único, al querer agregar un numero o valor ya existente me sale este error:

```
Value already in database or empty
```

Een la parte inferior del campo correspondiente a la tabla `registro`, ¿cómo o en dónde personalizo ese mensaje?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los validadores pueden recibir el parámetro `error_message` para reemplazar el mensaje por defecto:

```
db.registro.numero_documento.requires = IS_NOT_IN_DB(db, 'registro.numero_documento', error_message='Ya existe en la base de datos')
```

No olvides consultar la documentación.

### Referencias

- [Validators](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/34/07/forms-and-validators#Validators)